# How to exit '.elements' loop in Nightwatch

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I'm coming from Java world, so I'm struggling little bit with Nightwatch. I have use case where I'm getting list of all ids on the page and if it will match some id, it should click on it and exit the loop. But I've tried different things to exit the loop such as return, break, even wrapped try-catch and still no luck. If it was plain javascript above criteria should exit the loop. My code is:

```
browser.elements('css selector', `article${cardElement}`, function (res) {
    for (let elem of res.value) {
      browser.elementIdAttribute(elem.ELEMENT, 'data-id', function (idResult) {
        let id = idResult.value;
        if(id == '1018925') {
          browser.elementIdClick(elem.ELEMENT);
          return true;//tried break here as well
        }
      })
    }
})
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the selection of the element with your id as part of the css selector:
`article${cardElement} [data-id='1018925']`

However as you commented you are setting this dynamically. As such there are other functions that are more suited such as `perform`.

Any call added to browser still runs sequentially in the queue, so you can still run `browser.elementIdClick(elem.ELEMENT);` from within your `perform` call

Comment: In my case `data-id='1018925'` I just gave as an example. But original task is I have List1 of ids , then I navigate the page and getting ids from elements and should click on id that not in List1. As soon as I click I should exit that `browser.elements` loop

Comment: I think if that is the case then a more expanded code would help, I think there may be easier ways to do the whole thing as opposed to exiting a single loop. You can always use perform to do a loop you can break which can pass the value you find back to your script for example.

Answer (score 0):

What if you added a variable of "success", and break if it returns true?

```
browser.elements('css selector', `article${cardElement}`, function (res) {
  let success = false;
  for (let elem of res.value) {
    if (success === true) {
      break;
    }
    else {
      browser.elementIdAttribute(elem.ELEMENT, 'data-id', function (idResult) {
        let id = idResult.value;
        if (id == '1018925') {
          browser.elementIdClick(elem.ELEMENT);
          success = true;
        }
      })
    }
  }
});
```